# Android LayoutGravity with ScrollView, TableRow and TextView

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment, text-align

I have a setup of a `ScrollView` containing a `TableLayout` with some `TableRow`s.
One of the `TableRow`s has a `TextView` as a child.

All elements are centered, including the `TextView`, but I want to left-align the text in the textview.

I found no possible way to do this without the textview cutting out my `\n` and `\t`.

`android:textAlignment` doesn't work either and I don't want to use this due to the min API level it requires.

Is there a possible way to align text left in a centered textview?

**Some code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start">

<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
         >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_question_headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quiz_question_headline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >
        <!-- The textview, which text should be left-aligned -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quiz_question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>

...
```

Comment: Remove this line android:gravity="center" from TextView.

Comment: @Haresh Wrong textview, I've added a comment above the important textview. It hasen't a _android:gravity_ line.

Comment: your TextView text contain \t or \n ?

Comment: Yes, it does , to indent some code displayed there later.

Comment: Then simple replace with blank space.

Answer (score 0):

in your TextView  use `android:gravity="left"` instead of `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: _android:gravity="left"_ aligns the whole textview, but I don't want this, I just want to align the text IN this textview.

Comment: By default TextView text gravity is left.

Comment: no its not possible that whole textview is aligned.. pls update your edited answer

Comment: @Haresh my solution is not wrong u should notdownvote it

Comment: @jaimin,cool down i just try explain you and i never down vote your question okay ....

Comment: sorry i thought its you